# Run monero-wallet-rpc in background in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, monero-wallet-rpc

Is there a flag that i can pass to monero-wallet-rpc so it runs in the background? I tried --detach since thats used in monerod but it didn't work. Any unofficial way to do it easily?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: on linux you can always run `./monero-wallet-rpc &` or something similar.

Comment: So i just add the & sign and it will run in the background? I am on ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't find a flag and you run linux, you can use the usual way of sending an application to the background.

Start the application in the background:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc &
```

Additionally, don't show output on the terminal:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If you connect via ssh to launch the application, it will exit when you close the ssh session - you can use `nohup` to keep the application running after the ssh session is closed (the first command will put the output in nohup.out, the second will ignore the output):

```
nohup ./monero-wallet-rpc &
nohup ./monero-wallet-rpc > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I toyed with mentioning `screen` or `tmux`, which are mainly thought of to only be applicable to SSH sessions, but I think your answer is more specific and better.